# If date is in future have pop up box - Macro in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I need a macro script so that if the user enters a future date inside my form then a message box would inform them that they cannot enter a future date?

I don't understand how to do this at all as i am completely new to Macros inside Access!

Comment: If this is not allowed, consider setting a validation rule for the textbox, say `<Date()`

Comment: Hi i have added a validation but i need to implement a macro doing this... would it look something like: If [FieldName] <Date() then message box: [Message]? Thanks

Comment: When you say macro, do you mean VBA code or macros :), I can help you with VBA code, but I avoid macros.

Comment: There is also validation text associated with validation rules.

Comment: Hi it can be either VBA code would be helpful aswell Thank you

Answer (score 1):

At the simplest:

```
Private Sub ADate_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Me.ADate > Date Then
        ''Me.Undo
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "Earlier date, please."
    End If
End Sub
```

However, if you already have validation set, that will take priority, so you should either use Validation Text property, Form Error event, or remove validation.

Form error:

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)
      If DataErr = 2107 Then
         MsgBox "There was an error."
         Response = acDataErrContinue
      End If
End Sub
```

Comment: And, in place of me.undo, you can use cancel = True